# Обернуть html код в дополнительный div при перемещении с помощью .before js

Tags: javascript

Есть код, который перемещает `<div id="item_related_1">` и `<div id="item_related_2">` перед вторым тегом `<h2>` на странице

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Переместить #item_related_1 и #item_related_2 
        // перед вторым <h2>
        
        $('h2:eq(1)').before($('#item_related_1 , #item_related_2')); 
        });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как дополнить этот простой код, чтобы обернуть эти два блока в один общий div и получить на выходе:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="item_related_1">...</div>
   <div id="item_related_2">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно что-то из этого сделать.. Соответственно строки надо упаковать в тело ready функции. Здесь они вынесены для просмотра результата

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Переместить #item_related_1 и #item_related_2 
  // перед вторым <h2>

  $('h2:eq(1)').before($('#item_related_1 , #item_related_2'));
});

//$(".wrapper").append($('#item_related_1 , #item_related_2'));// если див с классом wrapper существует в DOM
//console.log($('body').html())

div = $("<div class='wrapper'>").html($('#item_related_1 , #item_related_2'));// создать див с классом wrapper и вставить внутрь блоки с id #item_related_1 , #item_related_2

$("body").prepend(div);//вставить в тело html

console.log($('body').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item_related_1">...</div>
<div id="item_related_2">...</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас! Ваш код отлично работает в примере, но почему то отказывается работать у меня, '.wrapper' не создается. Возможно это связано с нестандартным вызовом jQuerry в Joomla, к сожалению у меня совсем нет знаний по этой теме чтобы сказать определенно. Я попробовал поэкспериментировать с вашим кодом, тогда либо создается .wrapper и не происходит перемещение, либо наоборот. То есть срабатывает только одна часть функционала . Буду благодарен если подскажете, что можно еще попробовать

Comment: Возможно, сначала создаёте `div = $("<div class='wrapper'>..` добавляете `$("body").prepend(div);` затем перемещаете его со всем содержимым  `$('h2:eq(1)').before($('.wrapper'));` Если вам надо переместить исходные блоки `id="item..` а затем создать обернутые в .wrapper тогда создаёте клон `let clon = $('#item_related_1, #item_related_2').clone();` а затем помещаете в `div = $("<div class='wrapper'>").html(clon)` Если wrapper создаётся то "нестандартным вызовом jQuerry в Joomla" дело скорее всего не в этом.